# A minimally 2-connected graph H and a 3-connected graph H' both contain G, does H' contain H?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics

Does there exists a connected graph G which is a subgraph of two graphs H and H' for which

- G, H and H' have the same vertex set,
- H is minimally 2-connected (i.e. deleting any edge from H makes is not 2-connected),
- H' is 3-connected and
- H is not a subgraph of H'?

I arrived at this question when thinking about how grant applications with "anti-terrorism" in the title seem to get much more funding than those without.  I came out with this problem:  A terrorist wants to disconnect G by deleting edges.  To prepare for this attack, I want to add edges to G to make it 2-connected (i.e. H) at minimal cost, while at the same time preparing to make it 3-connected (i.e. H') at a later date.  Does the choice of H matter?

Comment: Usually $k$-connected means "vertex $k$-connected" but if your hypothetical terrorists prefer cutting cables to blowing up relay stations, take a long path for $G$, make it into a single loop to get $H$ and add all edges except the edge that you used to get $H$ to get $H'$. Can I have my grant now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fedja's comment definitely earns the grant.  A minimal example is to let G be a star with four leaves {1,2,3,4}, let H be the bowtie obtained from G be adding the edges 13 and 24, and let H' be the wheel obtained from G by adding the cycle 1234.